# How to sort a list into a custom order forming kind of distinct groups

Tags: java, java-stream, custom-sort

I have a list of unsorted strings, where entries are one of `{A,B,C,D}`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A","C","B","D","D","A","B","C","A","D","B","D","A","C"));
```

I need to sort / (group) them in a custom order taking one item at time to have a result like:

```
[A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D, A, D]
```

I am struggling to come up with an idea how to do so. Any help?

I have tried to use a custom `Comparator<String>` but not able to implement the logic that `first A < second A` and `first D < second A`.

Also tried `Stream. groupingBy`:

```
Collection<List<String>> coll = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s)).values();
```

which groups same strings into groups.

```
[[A, A, A, A], [B, B, B], [C, C, C], [D, D, D, D]]
```

But I am not sure how to take one element at a time from above lists till no elements are available. Does anyone have any approach on how to proceed here? Need a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Do you need to do this with a stream and a custom comparator? Or can you also use a different solution?

Comment: @vc73 I am open to any approach. It doesn't have to be with streams. I just tought  streams may have some magic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building a whole new list could lead to some other solutions, for example:

```java
Map<String, Long> counts = strings.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(), TreeMap::new, counting()));
List<String> ordered = new ArrayList<>();
while (!counts.isEmpty()) {
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> it = counts.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = it.next();
        ordered.add(entry.getKey());
        long newCount = entry.getValue() - 1;
        if (newCount == 0) {
            it.remove();
        } else {
            entry.setValue(newCount);
        }
    }
}
```

With `strings` being the input list and `ordered` the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. A direct approach which I like very much.  I can understand your steps well. My list will hardly have more than 250 entries, so I don't worry about having a second list regarding of performance.

Comment: Good answer, you were faster at implementing that logic. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Add a number prefix to each value, sort and remove the prefix, with limitation the array size cannot be far bigger than the number prefix

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A","C","B","D","D","A","B","C","A","D","B","D","A","C"));
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
strings.stream()
    .map(i -> String.format("%dx%s", (100000 + m.merge(i, 1, (n, w) -> n+w)), i))
    .sorted()
    .map(i -> i.replaceFirst("^\\d+x", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That looks very promising. Could you please describe what is going on at this line: `.map(i -> String.format("%dx%s", (100000 + m.merge(i, 1, (n, w) -> n+w)), i))`

Comment: converts first A to 100001xA and store A: 1 in Map, for next A, it updates the Map to A: 2, and to 100002xA

Answer (score 2):

This is roughly the same logic as [sp00m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586090/5761558), but implemented with two streams:

```
Map<String, Long> groups = strings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
            TreeMap::new, 
            Collectors.counting()));

List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, groups.values().stream()
                          .mapToInt(Long::intValue).max().orElseThrow())
    .mapToObj(c -> groups.keySet().stream().filter(k -> groups.get(k) > c))
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The sorting is taken care of by `TreeMap`. Just be sure that your actual list elements are comparable (or that you give the right TreeMap supplier)

Comment: It took me a while to understand the second part. I had to copy and past it into my IDE and go through parenthesis by parenthesis. The `orElseThrow` had me confused as I had missed a bracket and didn't realize that it belongs to the range. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is another approach.

First, we could get a list of a list with all items, as you describe in your question.

```
[
    [A, A, A, A],
    [B, B, B],
    [C, C, C],
    [D, D, D, D]
]
```

```java
Collection<List<String>> chunks = strs.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
    .values();
```

You could insert a custom `Comparator` by replacing `TreeMap::new` by `() -> new TreeMap<>(comparator)`.

Then we could just use this to get all `ABCD` groups.

```java
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
    .mapToObj(i -> chunks.stream()
        .map(sublist -> i < sublist.size() ? sublist.get(i) : null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toList())
    .takeWhile(list -> !list.isEmpty())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

What happens here, is that we loop over each sublist and take the 1st element, then the take each 2nd element, et cetera.

---

This'll become better readable if you put the code to get a certain index of a bunch of lists into a separate method:

```java
public static <T> Stream<T> nthElement(Collection<? extends List<T>> list, int index) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(sublist -> index < sublist.size() ? sublist.get(index) : null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

```java
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
    .mapToObj(i -> nthElement(chunks, i).toList())
    .takeWhile(list -> !list.isEmpty())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Pictorially very well comprehensible. I had an idea to turn the list into a 2d array and iterate column by column. But I got outOfBounds all the time. Very elegant to map first to null and filter afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant but more clear as to what is going on.  You can place an integer before each string indicating the amount of times that string value has been encountered.  Then just sort normally and use a regex to replace the integer values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A","C","B","D","D","A","B","C","A","D","B","D","A","C"));
    List<String> sortableString = stringTransform(strings);
    sortableString.stream().sorted().forEach(s -> System.err.print(s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "")));
}


private static List<String> stringTransform(List<String> stringList) {
    Map<String, Integer> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : stringList) {
        Integer integer = stringMap.get(string);
        if (integer == null) {
            integer = 0;
        } else {
            integer++;
        }
        stringMap.put(string, integer);
        result.add(integer + string);
    }
    return result;
}
```